# SLF4J multiple binding shaded

Tags: jar, slf4j

I have a shaded executable .jar that contains an embedded Jetty server.  I only have one version of SLF4J (1.6.1) as a dependency, however, when the .jar is shaded using the maven shade plugin, SLF4J sees this as having multiple bindings since the dependency is packaged on both the classpath  as well as at the root of the .jar

```
org
   |_ slf4j
     |_ ...
WEB-INF
   |_ lib
     |_ slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
     |_ slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar

`SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/episner/Desktop/rmt/webapp/WEB-INF/l
ib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/episner/Desktop/rmt-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT.w
ar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.`
```

Is there any way to either supress this message or modify my maven build to remove the duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your POM so that your dependencies do not pull SLF4J at all.
Hopefully they will all be happy with the SLF4J version already available on your classpath.

Something along the lines of

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```